# MongoDB aggregate pipeline and field matching

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I really need to understand if I made a broken design or I just don't find a right solution. A document in my collection looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : {
    "owner" : "eight@home",
    "day" : 5.0,
    "month" : 0.0
  },
  "value" : {
    "userId" : 7.0,
    "session" : 5.0,
    "no_closed" : 1.0,
    "data" : {
      "sentMessage" : [{
          "adId" : 19.0,
          "detail" : {
            "timestamp" : 1420806952000.0
          }
        }, {
          "adId" : 19.0,
          "detail" : {
            "timestamp" : 1420806969000.0
          }
        }],
      "receivedMessage" : [{
          "adId" : 1.0,
          "detail" : {
            "timestamp" : 1420806955000.0
          }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

What I need is to get all the documents where the sentMessage aapId field matches the receivedMessage appId. Imagine that users make use of different apps to message each other through the same server, and I need to find messages that were sent and received by a user through same app througout a certain period of time.

Thanks

Comment: No it doesn't look like that because it is an invalid structure. Your real structure is important to your question. Please correct. Which is it? Are "sentMessage" and "receivedMessage" in the same document for the array element? Or are they different array elements. Need to be within a document at least.

Comment: Please ping me with a message when you are finshed editing this. The structure here has changed more times than Michael Jackson's face.

Comment: Done  :) this is copy-paste from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes well your field appears to be called "adId" and not "aapId" as you claim. Not really helping that you didn't provide a sample of data for a positive match either. But oh well...

Mostly using [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$anyElementTrue`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) operators to traverse array elements for logical comparison.

Not ideal because you are relying on projection from the aggregation framework to decide if elements in the array have matching conditions. You could also code this in JavaScript with [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but that is probably even worse performance due to the evaluation of JavaScript code and object conversion:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
         "value": 1,
         "matched": {
             "$anyElementTrue": [
                 { "$map": {
                     "input": "$value.data.sentMessage",
                     "as": "sent",
                     "in": {
                         "$anyElementTrue": [
                             { "$map": {
                                 "input": "$value.data.receivedMessage",
                                 "as": "received",
                                 "in": {
                                     "$eq": [ "$$sent.adId", "$$received.adId" ]
                                 }
                             }}
                         ]
                     }
                 }}
             ]
         }
    }},
    { "$match": { "matched": true } }
])
```

Simple principle. Compare each array element against each other array element and look for the possibility of at least one match. Then the result is `true` and just return those that meet the conditions.